# Is there any open source topic-based subscriber/publish web service for SMS and email notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, publish-subscribe

I have the following requirement for my rails application.

My users will subscribe for updates by choosing different  categories and their preferences of receiving the updates (SMS or Email). They receive the updates according to their preferences when ever a update is posted on a particular category.

I am planning to implement a web service with the above functionality. The web service will

1. Expose an API to subscribe users for different categories.
2. Expose an API to post updates to a particular category.
3. Send out email or sms or both for all the subscribers to that particular category according to their preferences.

Is there any open source project or rails gem with the similar functionality or is it better to build my own web service. My application is in Rails3, but I can take the web service in any platform.

Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 1):

Since no body is cared to answer my query, lemme answer it.

I realized building a web service for such functionality is an overkill and there are no opensource projects running on the similar line. So i have decided to include the logic in my rails app rather than building it as a separate service.